# context?.save(nil) coming up with error

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

Using Xcode 7 and swift 2.0 if get the following error on the context?.save(nil).

Any help is appreciated

"cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'NSManagedObjectContext'

```
func newItem() {
    let context = self.context
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CallList", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let nItem = CallList(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    nItem.firstname = firstName.text
    nItem.lastname = lastName.text
    nItem.phonenumber = phoneNumber.text
    context?.save(nil)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get that error as your `context` variable is not optional so the `?` is useless.

Also swift 2 introduced the `do-catch` construct to allow advanced error handling as you would do in other languages with `try-catch`, so functions with an error parameter such as `save()` of `NSManagedObjectContext` changed and have lost the error parameter and report errors as exceptions; so you should do

```
do {
    try context.save()
} catch let error {
    // Handle error stored in *error* here
}
```

If you don't want to handle the error you can do

```
do {
    try context.save()
} catch {}
```